# How override the JavaScript prototype method into my normal JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have one method in JavaScript file which is written in prototype:

```
SMRangePickerCtrl.prototype.rangeSelected = function (range) {      

    var self = this;
    self.onRangeSelect({range: range});
    self.value = { startDate: range.startDateAsMoment, endDate: range.endDateAsMoment, __$toString: range.text };  
};
```

Now, I want to inherit this method in the separate JavaScript file.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit"?

Comment: I mean override the method into my custom code base.

Comment: Why do you not just change it in the original code? Is it a library that you are importing? If so, how are you using it? Where is the method being called?

Comment: Yes it is a library and i want to extend the functionality.

Comment: As I said, just edit the library source code. If that is not an option, give us more details. How is the library used? Where/how are the instances created? Where/how is this method called? Do you need instances with the original behaviour as well? What custom functionality do you want to add?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
var myMethod = SMRangePickerCtrl.prototype.rangeSelected;
myMethod(range);
```

If you need to add this method to some other object use the following:

```
myObj.rangeSelected = SMRangePickerCtrl.prototype.rangeSelected.bind(myObj);
```

Or if you have an instance of `SMRangePickerCtrl` class say `myAnotherObj` and want to override this method use:

```
myAnotherObj.rangeSelected = function(range) {
...
}
```

Or if you want to replace the method for all instances of `SMRangePickerCtrl` just use:

```
SMRangePickerCtrl.prototype.rangeSelected = function (range) {      
// My implementation here
};
```

Comment: No, definitely not. It's a method that you need to call on an instance.

Comment: Amit, I've added some suggestions to my answer.